# Bind zone transfer: slave can't resolve other slaves

Tags: bind, domain-name-system

We have a DNS config like this at work:

```
# company-master
zone master:  mycompany.com  

# city1-slave   
zone master: city1.mycompany.com
zone slave: mycompany.com

# city2-slave   
zone master: city2.mycompany.com
zone slave: mycompany.com
```

A master dns with the main zone and several slaves which are master of their own zones.

Zone declaration on city1-slave

```
zone "mycompany.com"{
        type slave;
        file "slaves/mycompany.com";
        masters { 192.168.1.5;};
};
```

From our LAN (city1) all queries to mycompany.com are resolved ok, the problem arises when we try to resolve city2.mycompany.com through our local slave server.

Is something wrong with city1-slave config?

Comment: What does happen? Are the delegatory NS records in place in the parent zone? Is the server you are sending the query to allowing recursion?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing delegation records for `city2` in the `mycompany.com` server, or maybe the delegation records are missing corresponding glue records. Please post the relevant records from `master/mycompany.com`.

Comment: Thanks both, it was right that, already fixed. The  thing is I'm only responsible for city1 server so I had no visibility outside this.